# ActionLink in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

This is my method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.clickableCell').click(function () {
        var currentObject = null; 
        currentObject = $(this).text();
        @Html.ActionLink("GetThis", "Get", new {theName = currentObject} )
    });
});
```

but it says that currentObject doesn't exist in the current context. How to resolve this?

Comment: You can not write asp.net mvc code in javascript

Comment: @JQone So how do I call the action method when a button is clicked?

Comment: sometimes it is best to dive in and ask the stupid questions. I find I learn quicker that way rather than trying to memories a book or 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `@Html.ActionLink` you should use the [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function.  `@Html.ActionLink is run on the server whereas the javascript is run on the client.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.clickableCell').click(function () {
        var currentObject = $(this).text();
        $.get('@Url.Action("GetThis", "Get")', {theName : currentObject});
    });
});
```

The `Url.Action` is rendered on the server and will give you the appropriate url.  The `$.get` will run a `get` request on the client.

Keep in mind, if this javascript is in a `.js` file, the `Url.Action` will not be run.  In that case you may simply want to replace it with `/Get/GetThis` or render the url in a hidden field on the page and get the value of the hidden field in your `.js` file.

You need an action method that looks like this in order to access the parameter:

```
public ActionResult GetThis(string theName)
{
    // manipulate theName
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it's not working :(
The name of the controller is GetController, the name of the actionMethod is GetThis. Should GetThis have parameters in its definition?

Comment: @John This still suffers from the same problem that the OP originally has, namely the mixing of client side code in server side code that has already run on the server and been delivered to the client

Comment: If this code is in a .cshtml page the server code will render the Url. I mentioned this in my last paragraph

Comment: @JohnKalberer What about my previous comment?

Comment: I forgot to wrap the Url.Action inside single quotes.  Try replacing that with /Get/GetThis as I said in my final paragraph to prove it is working.

Comment: @JohnKalberer Ok, but how do I access currentObject in the actionMethod?

Comment: Updated my answer and fixed an issue. That should give you the value when it hits the `Action`

Answer (score 4):

`currentObject` is a JavaScript String object that you are trying to pass into server side code. If you need to do this on the client side,

```
$(function () {
    $('td.clickableCell').click(function () { 
        var currentObject = $(this).text();

        // find the anchor element that you need to change,
        // then change the property on it to the value
        // of currentObject
        $('a').attr('title', currentObject);
    });
});
```

Alternatively, it's possible that you need to send the value to the server in some way. If the JavaScript above is within a Razor view, then

```
$(function () {
    $('td.clickableCell').click(function () { 
        var currentObject = $(this).text();

        // make a HTTP GET request and pass currentObject as a queryparam
        window.location = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")' + '?theName=' + encodeURIComponent(currentObject);
    });
});
```

The `'@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'` portion will have been evaluated on the server-side and been resolved by the UrlHelper to the URL to route to that controller action. We put this value in single quotes as we need to use it on the client side in a JavaScript variable. Then we add `currentObject` as a query parameter (and encode it at the same time).

Comment: So how can I pass it to the controller?

Comment: What do you need to pass to the controller - the value of `currentObject`? How should it be passed - via AJAX, a GET request, a POST request? If you can elaborate more on what you're trying to do, I'm sure I can help you

Comment: Yes, I need to pass the value of currentObject. GET.

Comment: But how to access currentObject in the actionMethod?

Comment: Updated example (was missing uqery string parameter name). Now, If your action method takes a `string theName` parameter, it will receive the value passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing client-side code with server-side code.  This line is being executed on the server *before* anything is sent to the client:

```
@Html.ActionLink("GetThis", "Get", new {theName = currentObject} )
```

That line, by itself, references something which doesn't exist.  `currentObject` won't exist until it's created in JavaScript on the client.  That JavaScript code, from the perspective of the server, is nothing more than text.